# Play/Pause remote key for UICollectionViewCell in tvOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos, apple-tv

My requirement is to play movies from `UICollectionView` directly by pressing play/pause remote key when cell is focused.

It is perfectly working if we go background(by pressing home button) and come to foreground (or) presenting `viewcontroller` and dismissing. But normal cases it is not working.

Play/Pause is not working for custom `AVPlayer` also as I am not using `avplayer` controls (here also Play/pause works like above cases)

Same code below

I am returning `UICollectionViewCell` whenever `preferredFocusEnvironments` gets called

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:SuggestionsCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SuggestionsCollectionViewCell
    let playPauseRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectThisMagazineCell))
        playPauseRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.playPause.rawValue)]
        playPauseRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(playPauseRecognizer)
return cell
}
```

For `AVPLayerViewController` class I have code like below for play/pause

```
let playPauseRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playPauseMenuButtonPressed))
    playPauseRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.playPause.rawValue)];
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(playPauseRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UICollectionViewCell` instead of the `AVPlayer`. The `UICollectionViewCell` will be the element capturing focus.

Add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on cell focus, and remove when the cell becomes unfocused.

Subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and `override` `didUpdateFocus` to capture the focus event:

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

    if isFocused {
        // Add gesture
    }
    else {
        // Remove gesture
    }
}
```

Then, in your `playPauseMenuButtonPressed` `func` call play/pause on the player the cell owns.